# How do i find the selected id and name of radiobutton list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I find the selected `id` of radiobutton in list.

Here is the radiobutton:

```
<input name="1" id="1" type="radio">
```

Radiobutton are dynamics.

Here is the dynamic radio button list.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>1. Here is the question??</label>
          <div class="icheck-list">
              <label class="icheck-list" id="1">

                  <input name="1" id="1" type="radio">Strongly Disagree
                  <span></span>
              </label>  
          </div>
          <div class="icheck-list">
              <label class="icheck-list" id="2">
                  <input name="1" id="2" type="radio">Disagree
                  <span></span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="icheck-list">
              <label class="icheck-list" id="3">
                  <input name="1" id="3" type="radio">Neither Agree or Disagree
                  <span></span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="icheck-list">
              <label class="icheck-list" id="4">      
                  <input name="1" id="4" type="radio">Agree
                  <span></span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="icheck-list">
              <label class="icheck-list" id="5">    
                  <input name="1" id="5" type="radio">Strongly Agree
                  <span></span>
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is 5 possible answers for a question.

I am using mvc 4.

For next question the i.e. for question 2.

The answer radiobutton is just like

```
<input name="2" id="11" type="radio">Strongly Disagree
```

So how do I find the selected radio button id and name???

here is the html i am using in view page.

```
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">

                                        @foreach (var items in Model.ParentList)
                                        {
                                            <div class="row">

                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                    <div class="col-md-12">


                                                        <label>@items.QuestionText</label>

                                                        @foreach (var ch in Model.ChildList)
                                                        {
                                                            if (items.QuestionId == ch.QuestionId)
                                                            {

                                                                <div class="icheck-list">
                                                                    <label class="icheck-list" id="@ch.AnswerId">
                                                                        @*<input type="checkbox"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Answers[j].AnswerText)*@
                                                                        <input name="@ch.QuestionId" id="@ch.AnswerId" type="radio">@ch.AnswerText
                                                                        <span></span>
                                                                    </label> </div>
 }

                                                        }
 </div>
</div>
 }
</div>
```

there is total 10 questions and each questions having 5 multiple choice answers.
so Model.ParentList i got total 10 questions with id
in Model.ChildList i got 50 answers.
so how do i bind and got the selected radio button value??

Comment: where do you want to use it - in controller or in javascript? if in controller, you need to give your radios a value attribute

Comment: your input and label have the same id. you should use `for` instead of `id` in label

Comment: how do i use different id???

Comment: @Pete i am not understand

Comment: can anyone told me how do i solve
??

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will return the value of the checked radio button in jQuery:

```
$('input[name=<name of radio>]:checked').val();
```

In your case with a radio named '1' it would be:

```
$('input[name=1]:checked').val();
```

I hope I have understood the question correctly, and that this might be of use for you.

Comment: var a= $('input[name=1]:checked').val();  a is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Please use value instead of id with each input, then you can try below code

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(event){
    console.log($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First attach an event listener which detects the change in selection.

```
jQuery( "input[name='1']" ).on( "click", function() {
  var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
  var name = jQuery(this).attr("name");
  alert("Id:"+ id);
  alert("Name: "+name);      

});
```

A similar method can be used where input[name='2']

Comment: some times it will coming "on"

Comment: after submit in form if i click then only show the id

Comment: How and when do you need the id and name ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139569/discussion-between-manoj-and-bimal).

Comment: See the last example in this page. You might get a solution. https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: i need to check only one radio button

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat